# R reorder dataframe within subject

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have a large dataset with repeat assessment across subjects. How do I go from:

```
subj, assessment, test1, test2  
A,    1,          10,    20  
A,    2,          12,    13  
A,    3,          11,    12  
B,    1,          14,    14  
B,    2,          13,    12
```

To:

```
subj, test1_1, test1_2, test1_3  
A,    10,      12,      11  
B,    14,      13
```

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 2):

you can easily accomplish this using the excellent reshape/ reshape2 package by hadley. here is the code to take you to what you need

```
library(reshape); 
df = melt(df, id = c('subj', 'assessment'));
df = cast(df, subj ~ variable + assessment);
```

let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I believe that should be "variable" instead of "test" in the cast formula, like so: df = cast(df, subj ~ variable + assessment). (Unless you add variable_name = "test" to the previous line).

Comment: that is right. thanks for pointing it out. i have modified the code accordingly

Answer (score 2):

The reshape function (in stats) does this fairly easily:

```
reshape(data, timevar='assessment', idvar='subj', dir='wide')
```

Or to just get the results for test1:

```
reshape(subset(data, select=-test2), timevar='assessment', idvar='subj', dir='wide')
```